# Why can't i get all routes from my project?

Tags: php, laravel

➜  voordeelpas git:(master) ✗ php artisan route:list

> [BadMethodCallException]
>     Method Cartalyst\Sentinel\Sentinel::inRole() can only be called if a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get your route list because there is an error you have to fix ...

Perhaps you mean to ask, "why am I getting this error?" :)